# Creating dynamic region content in wordpress as in drupal

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been using Drupal to create websites for about 2 months. I find it pretty easy to create a **view** or a **block** which could hold my dynamic content like latest photos, comments and all.

Now, i've started using Wordpress and it puzzles me how to do those things. Like, how to create a site like this:
http://theklaxon.com

Should i create a .php file which does what i want and then **include** the file in the respective places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of options you can explore. The easiest way to include your own block of content is through [page template](http://www.google.com.sg/url?q=http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages%23Page_Templates&usg=AFQjCNE_V0v80UFmj7z3W1pMjlDijtLhQQ&ei=15NZS6eOJJLs7AOD5OEF&sa=X&oi=section_link&resnum=1&ct=legacy&ved=0CA0QygQ); to make full use of it, you would have to understand the WordPress loop so you can fetch posts from the DB and format it as you like.

Another method, albeit which involves more coding and setup but more scalable in the long run, is the [Pods CMS for Wordpress](http://pods.uproot.us/). Do check the introductory articles there for what you can do with it.

Comment: Thanks for ur links. I'll check them